# Split on second delimiter value

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using delimiter to split one string example:

```
Test &&Product &Order &number &Test & Final
```

here delimiter is "&" here i want values as

```
Test &,Product, Order, number, Test & Final
```

first value should be `"Test &"` and last value should be `"Test & Final"` can anyone help me how to do this.

Comment: Anything you achieved so far?

Comment: `str = "Test &&Product &Order &number";`
`> str.split(/&(?!&)/);`

`> ["Test &", "Product ", "Order ", "number"]` as suggested by Alex able to get the first value but not able to create regex for last value

Answer (score 3):

Negative lookahead:

```
> str = "Test &&Product &Order &number";
> str.split(/&(?!&)/);

> ["Test &", "Product ", "Order ", "number"]
```

From your edit it looks like you are trying to parse a query string, there are better ways to do this than a RegEx but the problem is your query string is broken in that its been incorrectly encoded/decoded - an ampersand cannot appear within a value.  If you have access to the raw query string you should parse it correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Alex K. it is working in this case but have one more case when String is something like    '&orderIDType=PONUMBER&orderIDNumber=Final & Test&customerSoldTo=&customerShipTo=&orderStatus here orderIDNumber' value is complete String "Final & Test" but it is spliting on Final "&" Test please help to create a regex which will work for both.

Comment: yeah actually what i was trying to do to create a url with all the form values and then parsing the url to set the values in form and send ajax query to complete the search process we are doing this to maintain the search results on each page.

Comment: In your example here, the url should be: "&orderIDNumber=Final%20%26%20Test" - you're not url encoding (`escape` in js) the value *into* the url in the first place.

Comment: Yes, and when you do that you can read elsewhere with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript